# Moviepy write_videofile works the second time but not the first?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, moviepy

I'm concatenating a list of video objects together then writing them with write_videofile, weirdly enough the first time I write the file, it plays fine for the first halfish then the first few frames of each clip in the file afterwards plays before freezing. But here's the odd part, If I write the exact same video object right after the first video writes, it writes just fine and plays perfectly.

Here's my code

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips

clipslist = []
clips = ['https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C787619651.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C787628097.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/2222789345-offset-20860.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C787624765.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C787539697.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/39235981488-offset-3348.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C788412970.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C787682495.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C787962593.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C787627256.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C787573008.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C788543065.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C787593688.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C788079881.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C788707738.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C788021727.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C787595029.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/39233367648-offset-9536.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C788517651.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C788087743.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C787497542.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/39233367648-offset-9154.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/7109626012888880881-offset-4818.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/72389234-offset-760.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C787774924.mp4', 'https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C787565708.mp4']

for clip in clips:
    dlclip = VideoFileClip(clip, target_resolution=(1080, 1920))  # Download clip
    clipslist.append(dlclip)

videofile = concatenate_videoclips(clipslist)
videofile.write_videofile("final1.mp4") # Broken after the first halfish
videofile.write_videofile("final2.mp4") # Works entirely fine.
videofile.close
```

Any ideas? Any suggestions appreciated.

- Sometimes when the video is small enough it seems to write the first time just fine too.
- It seems there is no set point where it breaks, each time I write it for the first time it typically breaks at a different spot.
- I've tried waiting for the thread to exit and sleeping after the concatenation and that doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot consistently replicate the issue, it's most likely not an issue with your code.

Try opening the produced clip with a different program, such as VLC.

Answer (score 0):

I came across with the same problem when writting multiple videos at the same time with `write_videofile`, it seems like the later tasks will cause the wrong outputs of the previous `write_videofile` tasks by hanging their writting processes, although the processes will continue after the later tasks finish, the result videos of previous tasks break at the hanging spots, haven't found a solution

Comment: Using `logger=None` still no lucky.

Comment: I had this issue processing 2 videos at the same time. It was missing part of the audio in the second video. The solution was creating a unique path for temp_audiofile parameter:

video_clip.write_videofile(local_path, fps=24, audio_codec='aac', temp_audiofile=temp_audiofile)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue processing 2 videos at the same time. It was missing part of the audio in the second video. The solution was creating a unique path for the temp_audiofile parameter:

```
video_clip.write_videofile(local_path, fps=24, audio_codec='aac', temp_audiofile=temp_audiofile)
```